# Regarding concatenating prefix to a file

Tags: unix

I want to concatenate one prefix to the file inside `sh` script. Please suggest it. Is this correct?

For example:

```
file=a.txt
prefix=b

mv $file $prefix_$file

echo $prefix_$file
```

will it give me output like:

```
b_a.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

`_` is valid for a variable name, and so is considered part of the name.

```
mv "$file" "${prefix}_${file}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
prefix=b_
mv "$file" "$prefix$file"
```

As @Ignacio wrote, `_` is a valid character for a variable name, so in your example the shell is looking for a variable called `$prefix_`, which doesn't exist.